# Programmatically find the 'main' javascript file for libraries on GitHub

Tags: javascript, github, deployment, npm

I'm looking to find a way of finding the "key" javascript file from javascript libraries posted on GitHub in as automated as a way as possible.

So for example, this bootstrap extension called [Jasny](https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap/) has a ton of files on the GitHub page.  To get the key js file you have to go to '[dist/js/jasny-bootstrap.js](https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/js/jasny-bootstrap.js)' to find the needed file.  Is this file marked somehow?  Does npm have a way of getting this file?  Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the bower.json file, it has a main section!

Comment: Thanks.  Looking at it for Bootstrap,  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/bower.json.  The main links to the .js (yes) and the .less (no).  Instead of the .less is there a way to get the .css? https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/dist/css

Comment: you could get the .css file from package.json it has a style section